# Why are Callback functions represented by arguments[arguments.length-1] in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had copied a piece of code from somehwere which basically was used to extend the JQuery's hide method and extend it to call a callback

But am not clear with how the method works ..

```
       js.executeScript("window.webdrivercallback = function(){};" +

            "var _oldhide = $.fn.hide;" +
            "$.fn.hide = function(speed, callback) {" +
            "    var retThis = _oldhide.apply(this,arguments);" +
            "    window.webdrivercallback.apply();" +
            "    return retThis;" +
            "};"
    );
```

additionally in selenium webdriver code we have to add a piece of code something like:

```
js.executeAsyncScript("window.webdrivercallback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];");
```

I am unable to understand how can we create a javascript function webdrivercallback by just passing arguments like `arguments[arguments.length-1]`.What is the significance of this statement? What is `arguments` and from where are values being passed to the `arguments` field as I couldn't find a single place from where values were passed to arguments field.
Could someone help me understand this piece of code.

Comment: What is this I don't even

Comment: It's just using the last element in the array.

Comment: But,isn't window.webdrivercallback a function?can we define a function just by passing arguments like arguments[arguments.length - 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the last argument is a function, `arguments` is an array (well, very similar to an array) that contains all the parameters sent to the function.
So, `arguments[arguments.length-1]` will always be the last parameter sent to the function.

For example, consider you have:

```
function someFunction(param1, param2, param3){
    //arguments would have here: [param1, param2, param3]
    //so arguments[arguments.length-1] is the last param: param3
    var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1];   //This is what looks strange to you
    alert(typeof callback); //alerts 'function' if last param is well.. a function;
    callback();  //Execute the callback as a proof!   
}
```

so, let's call it:

```
someFunction('a', 'b', function(){
    alert("callback executed!!");
});
```

As you can see, it alerts "function", because the last parameter was a function. So, it can be assigned as a callback without problems.

Also, don't forget that we can call a function with more or less parameters than it was defined, so `arguments[arguments.length-1]` is a trick for always getting the last one.

Hope it's clear.

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.Its clear now.So,in my case it's a blank function as window.webdrivercallback=function(){}

Comment: Also,could you explain what does the statement do:var retThis = _oldhide.apply(this,arguments);

Comment: asuming arguments = `[1, 2, 3]` it's like doing `retThis = _oldhide(1, 2, 3)`. More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply